# How to implement Wallet Extension in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, apple-wallet

I am trying to implement Wallet Extension in My xamarin.forms App.

foreword: I connected my App to Apple and now I can add some internal cards to native Wallet App. It works good.

According the document by Apple (Getting_Started_with_Apple_Pay_In-App_Provisionin_Verification_Security_v4.pdf) Developers can implement some Wallet Extension to see the line "MyApp" on Wallet native App.

1. I added to my Xamarin App new project "Action Extension (iOS)"
2. According document I created unique bundle ID in developer.apple.com
3. Created some provision profiles

Added to this Extension Info.plist these lines:

`<key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key> <string>com.apple.PassKit.issuer-provisioning</string> <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key> <string>WalletViewController</string>`

4. Implemented just this file

   `namespace WalletExtension { public partial class WalletViewController : PKIssuerProvisioningExtensionHandler { public WalletViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { } } }`
5. Added this project as reference to main MyAppiOS project.
6. Built and created new IPA file.
7. Uploaded it to Test Flight.

According Apple documentation I launched the app first time from Test Flight. After it I go to native Wallet App and dont see any Rows with my App like "MyApp"

Help me to understand where some issues or mistakes.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?